# Trigger Qlik Sense Task with Python

Tags: qlikview, qliksense

I want to trigger Qlik Sense Task using Python.

So, I want to write code in python language that can trigger Qlik Sense Task in QMC.

Can someone guide me step by step? and also share the example code.

Thanks

I am looking for a solution that can trigger the task.

Answer (score 0):

May be able to provide step-by-step later but you essentially have to choose between using raw python vs using the Qlik Python SDK (see its [pipy page here](https://pypi.org/project/qlik-sdk/), which is a python wrapper around various Qlik Sense APIs. Either way, you'll want to follow the steps outlined in [this Qlik Help page](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/sense-developer/November2022/Subsystems/RepositoryServiceAPI/Content/Sense_RepositoryServiceAPI/RepositoryServiceAPI-Task-Start-Task.htm).

If using "raw" Python, you can do something like this:

```
import requests

url = "https://qlik.example.com/qrs/task/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000/start/synchronous"

querystring = {"Xrfkey":"12345678qwertyui"}

payload = "-----011000010111000001101001--\r\n\r\n"
headers = {
  "content-type": "multipart/form-data; boundary=---011000010111000001101001",
  "X-Qlik-Xrfkey": "12345678qwertyui"
}

response = requests.request("POST", url, data=payload, headers=headers, params=querystring)

print(response.text)
```

...where the task ID is specified in URL, shown in the example above as `00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000`.

That code kicks off a reload, but it assumes you're already authenticated. It also doesn't handle the polling to check if/when the task finishes, if that's even necessary to you.